# How to estimate the required time and computational needs before the actual training of a ML model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, cpu

Is there any way to estimate the required computational memory and time before the actual training of a machine learning model?

I am using a laptop without GPU and don't have any AWS credit left.. how not to overload my CPU? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Typically, training time grows as some convex function of the number of samples `N` for large-ish `N`.  Thus, one could train one's model on several random subsets of the training data of various sizes (smaller than `N`) and measure the time taken to train.  Plot this, and try to extrapolate.